# Creating a dummy MNIST dataset

Tags: file, binary, tensorflow-datasets, file-format, mnist

I want to create a subset (dummy) of the MNIST dataset. I want to create it in a similar format as mentioned on the MNIST's official page (`FILE FORMATS FOR THE MNIST DATABASE` section in http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). I want to add the magic number and other dimensions for my dummy dataset

I am not able to understand how to create the IDX binary format from the numpy arrays or CSV (MNIST images after extraction, from which I want to subset).

Answer (score 1):

The Pypy module idx2numpy helped me to solve the problem. I converted the `idx` to `numpy`, took a subset of the data and then converted the subset back to `idx` format.